# DecoView Label on click listener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have been using DecoView to create circle with numbers. 
Does anyone know how to get onClickListener for those numbers only? I can only set onClickListener to whole DecoView widget, but not for number labels.

DecoView: https://github.com/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting

And here it is. This is how it looks like in my app. I need to be able to get values from the numbers I click on.
[DecoView example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acJUt.png)

Any help is appreceated. If you know any other way I can get same result (circle with numbers) without using DecoView, please let me know.